# problems seeing some aspects on the desktop

Tags: desktop, release-hera

I have installed eOS 5.1 Hera (ubuntu 18.04.3 based) with linux kernel 5.3.0-26 and GTK 3.22.30.
In the last upgrade I can't see well some desktop items (pay atemption to top and bottom):

[image: desktop]

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: there is some problem on computers with Radeon video cards, check out the questions already asked here, somebody has found a solution.